# Do we need a scheduled refresh with Live Connection?

Tags: powerbi, ssas-tabular, liveconnect

I am working on SSAS Tabular project and I am using Live Connection when importing data to Power BI.
Do I need to schedule refresh in Power BI ?

Answer (score 0):

[Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data#datasets-in-directqueryliveconnect-mode) does not import data over connections that operate in DirectQuery/LiveConnect mode. Instead, the dataset returns results from the underlying data source whenever a report or dashboard queries the dataset. Power BI transforms and forwards the queries to the data source.

Although DirectQuery mode and LiveConnect mode are similar in that Power BI forwards the queries to the source, it is important to note that Power BI does not have to transform queries in LiveConnect mode. The queries go directly to the Analysis Services instance hosting the database without consuming resources on shared capacity or a Premium capacity.

Because Power BI does not import the data, you don't need to run a data refresh. However, Power BI still performs tile refreshes and possibly report refreshes, as the next section on refresh types explains. A tile is a report visual pinned to a dashboard, and dashboard tile refreshes happen about every hour so that the tiles show recent results. You can change the schedule in the dataset settings,  or force a dashboard update manually by using the Refresh now option.